# Custom response 403 error header from ConfigureServices method on Startup.cs aspnet core app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want to send custom HTTP Response when the user have not confirmed email yet. The following code set the confirmation required but I dont know how to send a 403 custom header error. Any ideas ?

Code on class startup.cs, method ConfigureServices.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
```

I dont have any clue about how to set response header for Identity middleware configuration.